# How addtag to the fragment in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

There are several fragments in my viewpager.I am calling downloading file from each fragment.So when downloading callback comes i need to update the relevant fragment.So i need to find the relevant fragment.How to add a tag to fragment in viewpager ? as it default adding tag can we overrides that tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question, what I understood is that you are using a FragmentViewPager with many fragments and you are download content in each fragments. The download callback is received in your acitivity and you need to update the relative fragment. If my assumption is true, you don't need to go for tagging, you will be having fragments in the FragmentViewPagerAdapter with their corresponding index. So whenever your download progress comes, you can find the relevant fragment using that index I guess.

Comment: I tried with below option,but it gives me exception sayng that fragment is already added. ScreenSliderFragment fragment = new ScreenSliderFragment(covers.get(position), ScreenSliderActivity.this);
   
   mPageReferenceMap.put(position, ""+position);
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(fragment, ""+position).commit();

Answer (score 0):

I used FragmentStatePagerAdapter.I am creating fragments inside the adapter getitem method.So if i try to get the fragment using getItem it will create a new fragment.In this case how do i get the relevant fragment?